# How to find and remove child_id if parent_id exist already

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have 2 tables of hierarchy data both in Parent Child & flattened structure

Parent Child table:

```
PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID 
1234        1111 
1234        2222 
1234        3333 
3333        33XX 
3333        33YY
```

Flattened Structure :

```
LEVEL_1 LEVEL_2 LEVEL_3
1234    1111    
1234    2222    
1234    3333    33XX
1234    3333    33YY
```

I have another user table which contains which user has access to which ID

```
USER_ID   USER_ACCESS
USER_A    1234,1111 
USER_B    33YY,3333,1234
```

I have further transformed the above table into the below format

```
USER_ID   USER_ACCESS
USER_A    1234
USER_A    1111 
USER_B    33YY
USER_B    3333
USER_B    1234
```

I need find and remove for each user the child_id if parent_id already exist for his ID

Sample Output for the above

```
USER_ID   USER_ACCESS
USER_A    1234
USER_B    1234
```

Need a solution in either Oracle/SQL Server avoiding any loops.

Comment: I'm lost.  You say. you have "a table".  Then you have example data with two columns and three columns.  That is not a single table.

Comment: And USER_ACCESS is a "csv column"? Joy

Comment: @CaiusJard its a varchar column, the ID's are separated by comma

Comment: That's a shame.

Comment: @CaiusJard why so ?

Comment: Because it makes it really awkward to work with.. you've got every variation from good (hierarchical two column parent child) to reasonable (flattened table of 3 columns limit on hierarchy) to awful (csv column)

Comment: I removed the "PL/SQL" tag because of the "avoiding any loops"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some remarks:

Having a hierarchy structure already makes the need for a flattened structure obsolete.
Also the flattened table can never accommodate all levels of the hierarchy structure. Every level you add, would require you to add an extra column which is ludicrous.

Storing the user access in such a way that you need to comma seperate keys, gives you no (good) way to verify contraints between the tables.

That being said (and using the tables that don't require string splitting):

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #struct_info;
CREATE TABLE #struct_info (
  PARENT_ID VARCHAR(50),
  CHILD_ID VARCHAR(50)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #access_info;
CREATE TABLE #access_info (
  USER_ID VARCHAR(50),
  USER_ACCESS VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #struct_info
(
  PARENT_ID,
  CHILD_ID
)
VALUES
('1234','1111'),
('1234','2222'),
('1234','3333'),
('3333','33XX'),
('3333','33YY')

INSERT INTO #access_info
(
  USER_ID,
  USER_ACCESS
)
VALUES
('USER_A','1234'),
('USER_A','1111'),
('USER_B','33YY'),
('USER_B','3333'),
('USER_B','1234')


SELECT * FROM #struct_info
SELECT * FROM #access_info

;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    PARENT_ID,
    CHILD_ID
  FROM #struct_info
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    cte.PARENT_ID,
    si.CHILD_ID
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN #struct_info si
    ON si.PARENT_ID = cte.CHILD_ID
)
DELETE ai
FROM #access_info ai
WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM cte 
     WHERE cte.CHILD_ID = ai.USER_ACCESS
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM #access_info ai2 
                   WHERE ai2.USER_ID = ai.USER_ID
                     AND ai2.USER_ACCESS =  cte.PARENT_ID)
  )

SELECT * FROM #access_info
```

The cte determines all hierarchy variantions possible
The delete find any child_id where a parent can be found in that variation

Answer (score 0):

oracle

The design of the Parent Child table is so terrible,you better add the row with `child_id:1234`,just like the `tab1`

```sql
with tab1 as (
SELECT * FROM struct_info union all
SELECT distinct null, t1.parent_id FROM struct_info t1 
 where t1.parent_id not in (select distinct v1.child_id from struct_info v1)
)
,tab2 as (
select t1.*,
       level lv
  from tab1 t1
 start with t1.parent_id is null
connect by prior t1.child_id = t1.parent_id
)
select distinct 
       t2.user_id,
       first_value(t1.child_id) over(partition by t2.user_id order by t1.lv)
  from tab2 t1,
       access_info t2
 where t1.child_id = t2.user_access
;
```